# Calling a Web Api 2 Method using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web Api 2 project which I used for a mobile project. I am trying to use the same api's for a web project but am unable to reach them using ajax. I've confirmed that my url is correct and I am able to hit the endpoint from an android project and from fiddler. Am I missing something is my ajax call? I always hit the error function, which returns 'undefined'. I can set a breakpoint in my webapi project and that endpoint is never being hit.

```
// GET: api/Trips
public IQueryable<Trip> GetTrips()
{
     return db.Trips.Include("Users");
}
```

jquery

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:49669/api/Trips',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success!!");

                },
                error: function (x, y) {
                    alert(x.response);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to enable CORS if trying to hit your API form a browser.

Step 1, modify your WebApiConfig file (App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs):

```
using System.Web.Http;
namespace WebService
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Add this line
            config.EnableCors();

            // the rest of your code
        }
    }
}
```

Step 2, add the [EnableCors] attribute to your Web API controller:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://www.whatever.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class HelloWorldController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/Trips
        public IQueryable<Trip> GetTrips()
        {
          return db.Trips.Include("Users");
         }
    }
}
```

**Note: ** You may also need to install the CORS nuget package.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

Comment: This was exactly it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`contentType` is for the content type beint *sent* to the server; this is the only possible reason I can imagine your code not working since you said it's never actually making the request so it must be some error handling done by jQuery before making the request, and the error is being thrown because you are trying to specify `contentType` for a `GET` request.

The property for specifying a response type is `dataType`. Try changing `contentType` to `dataType`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It also errors when I don't specify a contentType. Do I need to specify if I am not sending a content type at all?

Comment: No, in fact for `GET` requests the contentType field should be ignored completely. Are you getting any error messages in the browser debugger?

Comment: Also in the `error` function try `alert`ing `y` since the second parameter is the error status, and add a third parameter which is an error message string (from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))

Comment: It seems that all I get is 'error' when trying alert(y + z);

Comment: Ah ha! I'm getting the error in Chrome: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. I'm guessing I need something in my web api controller to allow the request

Comment: Yes it's CORS, see my answer below. :)